# Understanding ideals generated by $\langle a_1, ..., a_n \rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

The book I'm reading defines an ideal generated by $\langle a_1, ..., a_n \rangle$ as $I = \langle a_1, ..., a_n \rangle = \{r_1a_2 + ... + r_na_n: r_i \in R\}$.

So for $Z[x]$, the ring of all polynomials with integer coefficients, and $I$ (the subset of $Z[x]$ with even constant terms), $I$ is an ideal and $I = \langle x, 2 \rangle$.

But if $r_1 = 3x^2 + 2x$ and $r_2 = x^3 + 1$
, then $(3x^2+2x)x + (x^3+1)2 = 5x^3 + 2x + 2$ which is not in $I$.

What am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: One of the elements you started with is not in the ideal, so why do you expect the linear combination to be?

Comment: Why do you think $5x^3+2x+2$ is not in the ideal?

Comment: Why do you think it is not in $I$? It is of the form $r_1 x + r_2 2$, therefore it is in $I= \langle x, 2\rangle$.

Comment: @FredrikMeyer Because $I$ is the subset of $Z[x]$ of even constant terms, and the leading constant term is $5$.

Comment: The *leading* constant term is 5, not the *constant* one, so there is no problem.

Comment: @OliverG The constant term is just the term without an $x$, so $I$ is the set of all polynomials of the form $a_n x^n + \dots + a_1 x + a_0$ with $a_0$ even; and not with all $a_i$ even.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ideal $I$ is just the set of polynomials of the form
$$f(X)=XP(X)+2Q(X) \qquad P,Q \in \Bbb Z[X]$$
It is equal to
$$\{2a_0+a_1X+\cdots+a_nX^n \mid a_i \in \Bbb Z, n ≥ 0\}$$

Your polynomial $5X^3+2X+2$ has this form, with $a_3=5,a_1=2,a_2=0,a_1=1$. So it belongs to $I$.

Comment: I see now, thank you.  I misread the wording of "constant term".